# Spring JPA / Hibernate transaction force insert instead of update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Edited.  Whilst extending the base repository class and adding an insert method would work an more elegant solution appears to be implementing Persistable in the entities.  See **Possible Solution 2**

---

I'm creating a service using `springframework.data.jpa` with Hibernate as the ORM using `JpaTransactionManager`.

following the basis of the tutorial here.
http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-jpa-tutorial/

My entity repositories extend `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository`

I'm working with a legacy database which uses meaningful primary keys rather then auto generated id's

This situation shouldn't really occur, but I came across it due to a bug in testing. Order table has a meaningful key of OrderNumber (M000001 etc).  The primary key value is generated in code and assigned to the object prior to save.  The legacy database does not use auto-generated ID keys.

I have a transaction which is creating a new order. Due to a bug, my code generated an order number which already existed in the database (M000001)

Performing a repository.save caused the existing order to be updated.  What I want is to force an Insert and to fail the transaction due to duplicate primary key.

I could create an Insert method in every repository which performs a find prior to performing a save and failing if the row exists.  Some entities have composite primary keys with a OrderLinePK object so I can't use the base spring FindOne(ID id) method

Is there a clean way of doing this in spring JPA?

I previously created a test service without jpa repository using spring/Hibernate and my own base repository. I implemented an Insert method and a Save method as follows.

This seemed to work OK.
The save method using `getSession().saveOrUpdate` gave what I'm experiencing now with an existing row being updated.

The insert method using `getSession().save` failed with duplicate primary key as I want.

```
@Override
public Order save(Order bean) {

    getSession().saveOrUpdate(bean);
    return bean;
}

@Override
public Order insert(Order bean) {
    getSession().save(bean);
    return bean;
}
```

---

### Possible solution 1

Based on chapter 1.3.2 of the spring docs here 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Probably not the most efficient as we're doing an additional retrieval to check the existence of the row prior to insert, but it's primary key.

Extend the repository to add an insert method in addition to save.  This is the first cut.

**I'm having to pass the key into the insert as well as the entity.  Can I avoid this ?**

**I don't actually want the data returned.  the entitymanager doesn't have an exists method (does exists just do a count(*) to check existence of a row?)**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

/**
 *
 * @author Martins
 */
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface IBaseRepository <T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

    void insert(T entity, ID id);    

}
```

Implementation : Custom repository base class.
Note : A custom exception type will be created if I go down this route..

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> 
        extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements IBaseRepository<T, ID> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
        this.entityManager = em;
    }


    public BaseRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super (entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;

    }

    @Transactional
    public void insert(T entity, ID id) {

        T exists = entityManager.find(this.getDomainClass(),id);

        if (exists == null) {
          entityManager.persist(entity);
        }
        else 
          throw(new IllegalStateException("duplicate"));
    }    

}
```

A custom repository factory bean

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * This factory bean replaces the default implementation of the repository interface 
 */
public class BaseRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable>
  extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

  protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {

    return new BaseRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
  }

  private static class BaseRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public BaseRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
      super(entityManager);

      this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

      return new BaseRepositoryImpl<T, I>((Class<T>) metadata.getDomainType(), entityManager);
    }

    protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

      // The RepositoryMetadata can be safely ignored, it is used by the JpaRepositoryFactory
      //to check for QueryDslJpaRepository's which is out of scope.
      return IBaseRepository.class;
    }
  }
}
```

Finally wire up the custom repository base class in the configuration

```
// Define this class as a Spring configuration class
@Configuration

// Enable Spring/jpa transaction management.
@EnableTransactionManagement

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.savant.test.spring.donorservicejpa.dao.repository"}, 
        repositoryBaseClass = com.savant.test.spring.donorservicejpa.dao.repository.BaseRepositoryImpl.class)
```

---

### Possible solution 2

Following the suggestion made by [patrykos91](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630520/patrykos91)

Implement the `Persistable` interface for the entities and override the `isNew()`

A base entity class to manage the callback methods to set the persisted flag

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.PostLoad;
import javax.persistence.PostPersist;
import javax.persistence.PostUpdate;


@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable{

    protected transient boolean persisted;


    @PostLoad
    public void postLoad() {
        this.persisted = true;
    }

    @PostUpdate
    public void postUpdate() {
        this.persisted = true;
    }

    @PostPersist
    public void postPersist() {
        this.persisted = true;
    }

}
```

Then each entity must then implement the `isNew()` and `getID()`

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MTHSEQ")
@XmlRootElement

public class Sequence extends BaseEntity implements Serializable, Persistable<SequencePK> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected SequencePK sequencePK;
    @Column(name = "NEXTSEQ")
    private Integer nextseq;

    public Sequence() {
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return !persisted;
    }

    @Override
    public SequencePK getId() {
        return this.sequencePK;
    }



    public Sequence(SequencePK sequencePK) {
        this.sequencePK = sequencePK;
    }

    public Sequence(String mthkey, Character centre) {
        this.sequencePK = new SequencePK(mthkey, centre);
    }

    public SequencePK getSequencePK() {
        return sequencePK;
    }

    public void setSequencePK(SequencePK sequencePK) {
        this.sequencePK = sequencePK;
    }

    public Integer getNextseq() {
        return nextseq;
    }

    public void setNextseq(Integer nextseq) {
        this.nextseq = nextseq;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (sequencePK != null ? sequencePK.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Sequence)) {
            return false;
        }
        Sequence other = (Sequence) object;
        if ((this.sequencePK == null && other.sequencePK != null) || (this.sequencePK != null && !this.sequencePK.equals(other.sequencePK))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.savant.test.spring.donorservice.core.entity.Sequence[ sequencePK=" + sequencePK + " ]";
    }



}
```

It would be nice to abstract out the isNew() but I don't think I can.  The getId can't as entities have different Id's, as you can see this one has composite PK.

Comment: What solution did you actually implement? I'm having the same issue and your 2nd option seems like a good fit. Also, why not move your 2 options to actual answers to the question?

Comment: I went with solution 2. As i said it does mean each entity must implement IsNew and getId so there's some additional work to do for each entity, but it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I never did that before, but a little hack, would maybe do the job.

There is a `Persistable` interface for the entities. It has a method `boolean isNew()` that when implemented will be used to "assess" if the Entity is new or not in the database. Base on that decision, EntityManager should decide to call `.merge()` or `.persist()` on that entity, after You call `.save()` from `Repository`.

Going that way, if You implement `isNew()` to always return true, the `.persist()` should be called no mater what, and error should be thrown after.

Correct me If I'm wrong. Unfortunately I can't test it on a live code right now.

Documentation about `Persistable`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have a look.  I'm currently attempting to add a custom "insert" method to a base repository to check existance before inserting - as described in spring docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html  Unfortunately the docs seem out of date, I'm getting No suitable constructor trying to create my base repository extending SimpleJpaRepository.

Comment: Using your suggestion implementing Persistable and using callback methods @ PostLoad, @ PostUpdate, @ PostPersist seems quite an elegant way of achieving what I want.  At least I got some experience at implementing custom repository base classes along the way.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a clone object which clones everything except your primary keys and then save this cloned object.

Since the PK will not be present, an insert happens, instead of an update

Comment: I may have been unclear. The primary keys are created internally and assigned to the object rather than being auto-generated on insert. Some tables have multiple primary key fields too

Comment: That would make it even easier. After cloning all the common fields, why not assign the required values to the entity id's and do a save. Or is this not possible?

Comment: It was only due to a bug.  I was intending to insert a new order, but I assigned the wrong primary key and an existing order was updated.  This is obviously really bad in a live environment so I want to eliminate the possibility of this happening.  The code needs to explicitly call an insert method which should fail if the row already exists, not leave it to the spring JPA framework to decide whether to insert or update (which would work fine for database auto-generated ID primary keys)

Comment: The only way I can think of is to have a select/ load call yourself to check if such a record is already present in the DB and then throw a user defined exception which lets you handle the cause as you deem fit.

Comment: So there's no way of making Spring-data JPA perform a save() rather than a SaveOrUpdate() ?  I will have to add an insert(order) method to my OrderRepository interface like i did before using spring-data and JPA.  But now I need to code an implementation for the insert(order) which checks for the record rather than letting the database reject with 'Duplicate primary key' error.  That's a shame.

Comment: There could be a way to do that. But, sadly I am not aware of it.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value, if I am doing record.setId(null)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

Set `updatable = false` on your PK column definition. Example:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = “id”, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

Setting your id non updatable will stop JPA from doing updates on your primary key, so thing about it.

Answer (score 0):

One option that worked for me, although isn't particularly elegant, but is at least very explicit: Define your own `insert` method on your JpaRepository and then call it from your code.

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyRecord, Integer> {
    
    ....

    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO my_table (field1, field2) "
        + "VALUES (:#{#c.field1}, :#{#c.field2})", nativeQuery = true)
    public void insert(@Param("c") MyRecord c);

}
```

And then in the code doing the insert:

```
final var newRecord = MyRecord.builder()
    .field1(...)
    ....
    .build();

try {
    myRepository.insert(newRecord);
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    ....
}
```