# How to let JPArepository.save() do insert only and prevent update?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPArepository.save() to insert the record to the database but it will automatically update the existing record in the database. What I want to do is let it throw exception if there are records with same primary key in the database.

I searched the solution in Google and find a solution that said use saveAndFlush instead of save can solve it. However, it still update the existing record after I used saveAndFlush.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring JPA / Hibernate transaction force insert instead of update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253175/spring-jpa-hibernate-transaction-force-insert-instead-of-update)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution.
I just implement Persistable interface and ovrride the isNew() to be always true.

Example:

```
@Entity
public class ChessGame implements Persistable<Long> {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;

 
    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if Accepted answer has an code example without just saying the approach

Comment: @MenukaIshan updated example

Comment: this is not working...

Comment: @Michael why not working? can u show any error log?

Comment: @MichaelTsai i still have an update query

Comment: @Michael did u return true in the isNew method? or can u reproduce ur code sample?

Comment: Yeah i just return true

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do just an INSERT without UPDATE in JPA out-of-the-box.

You need to define your own INSERT method on your JpaRepository and then call it from your code.

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyRecord, Integer> {
    
    ....

    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO my_table (field1, field2) "
        + "VALUES (:#{#c.field1}, :#{#c.field2})", nativeQuery = true)
    public void insert(@Param("c") MyRecord c);

}
```

And then in the code doing the insert:

```
final var newRecord = MyRecord.builder()
    .field1(...)
    ....
    .build();

try {
    myRepository.insert(newRecord);
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    ....
}
```